# MPAndroidChart Chart shows with zoom on X Axis when too many entries

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I'm using MPAndroidChart and when there are many entries (more than 30 on my device), the charts appear to have an automatic zoom, since the X axis only shows even values at start.

[Chart with zoom on X axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpiK1.png)

Then when doing a zoom on the chart (on the screen or by code `chart.zoom(2, 0, 0, 0)`) all values on x axis are shown.

Since the number of entries to cause the automatic zoom seems to depend on the device screen size (therefore zooming programatically doesn't seem to be a good option), is there a way to force the chart not to have this zoom?

I already tried `chart.getXAxis().setLabelCount(entries.size(), true)`, but doesn't work.

Here is the sample code I've been using:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              tools:context="chart.test.MainActivity">

    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
        android:id="@+id/chart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

---

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LineChart chart = findViewById(R.id.chart);

        List<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i <= 60; i++) {
            entries.add(new Entry(i, i));
        }

        LineDataSet dataSet = new LineDataSet(entries, "Label");
        LineData lineData = new LineData(dataSet);

        chart.setData(lineData);
        chart.getXAxis().setLabelCount(entries.size());
        chart.invalidate();
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Buddy its difficult for me to understand what actually do u want? Do you want to show all values upon load ? Or do you want that upon load you fix number of entries like show 10 entries then for next you have to scroll?

Comment: Hi @M.SaadLakhan, originally I meant showing all values upon load, but a scroll as you mentioned is not a bad idea, if possible.

Comment: Buddy I added answer to fix number of entries on your chart. please do try that I will be happy if it helps you. Do let me know if you need more help. Happy coding :)

Comment: your welocome mate. happy coding :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix number of entries on your chart like if you want to show only 10 values on graph out of lets say 50 values then you should add following line to your code:

```
chart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(10);
```

You can change your number as per your requirements. This will show only 10 values to user upon load to see next values user have to scroll the chart.

Also remove following line from your code:

```
chart.getXAxis().setLabelCount(entries.size());
```

And also you dont need following line:

```
chart.invalidate();
```

Because when you call setData() method by default it call invalidate().
You need to call it only after you implement some changes to your axis or viewport or dataset after setting the data to your chart.

Comment: hi saad, i have an issue with auto zooming with bar chart large data. with setvisiblexRangemaximum(6)  . My data plotted good through this limit of 6 . after that chart zoomed and bar width also increased because of this. how can i  fix this zoom to not increase the bar width .